# Imported And Standalone Functions

Tags: python, cygwin

**There were logical errors and typo on my code, have been edited and published here**

First file: foo.py

```
import bar
def myname_foo():
    if __name__=='foo':
        print("foo: I have been imported")
    if __name__=='__main__':
        print("foo: I am on my own, i.e., standalone")

if __name__=='__main__':
    myname_foo()
    bar.myname_bar()
```

Second file: bar.py

```
import foo
def myname_bar():
    if __name__=='bar':
        print('bar: I have been imported')
    if __name__=='__main__':
        print('bar: I am on my own, i.e., standalone')

if __name__=='__main__':
    myname_bar()
    foo.myname_foo()
```

The outputs are:

```
$ python foo.py
foo: I am on my own, i.e., standalone
bar: I have been imported
```

```
$ python bar.py
bar: I am on my own, i.e., standalone
foo: I have been imported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check better your code

```
import foo
def myname_bar():
    if __name__=='foo':
                  ^^^ bar  


if __name__=='__main__':
    myname_bar()
    bar.myname_foo()
    ^^^ foo
```

after that

```
$ python  foo.py
foo: I am on my own, i.e., standalone
bar: I have been imported

$ python  bar.py
bar: I am on my own, i.e., standalone
foo: I have been imported
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, should use `__main__` instead of `main`. See [**main** — Top-level script environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) as an example.